# Dynamic height with tableview from HTML content

Tags: html, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, height

I want to use tableview to show the Message board ,

and the content is HTML file ,

But how should I use dynamic height of my TableViewItem?

I use the

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
                                    initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] 
                                    options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } 
                                    documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
self.d_content.attributedText = string
```

to show the HTML content (text + image)

But how should I make it with proper height

or say how should I calculate the height of HTML content?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just store your data in a UILabel in the UITableViewCell and use the method

```
[Label sizeToFit];
```

so the label will fit the text in it and will get bigger with height.

then use this method to set the row's height dependently on the text height

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

**@EDIT**

And set the number of lines of textfield equal to 0.